# Plotting graphs lines based on Long format using Plotly in python

Tags: python, graph, time-series, plotly

MY dataset looks like attached below

```
|CREDIT_ENTITY TENOR    SPREAD  SNAPSHOT_DATE|

|ABC              1Y    127.161 14/09/2017|

|ABC              3Y    150.161 14/09/2017|

|ABC              5Y    180.161 14/09/2017|

|ABC              7Y    111.161 14/09/2017|

|ABC              10Y   128.161 14/09/2017|

|ABC              1Y    123.161 15/09/2017|

|ABC              3Y    145.161 15/09/2017|

|ABC              5Y    196.161 15/09/2017|

|ABC              7Y    111.161 15/09/2017|

|ABC              10Y   134.161 15/09/2017|

|ABC              1Y    109.161 25/09/2017|

|ABC              3Y    190.161 25/09/2017|

|ABC              5Y    180.161 25/09/2017|

|ABC              7Y    127.161 25/09/2017|

|ABC              10Y   170.161 25/09/2017|
```

I would like to plot a graph for such dataset having a curve for each tenor.
I use the following command.

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.line(Final_DF, x="SNAPSHOT_DATE", y="SPREAD", color="TENOR")
fig.show()
```

[However on plotting the graph, I get a different curve for each date that is really weird.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57IKv.png)

I would like to ask if someone can help?
Thank you

Comment: You can use `pandas.Dataframe` methods to plot your data effectively. What happens if you do `Final_DF.plot(x='SNAPSHOT_DATE', y='SPREAD')`([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html))? I do not understand how you would like to have a graph for each tenor, since every row contains only one date (x value) and one spread value (y value). So if you really want a graph for each tenor, meaning each row, you have to add an example.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, what I want is a graph for all 5 tennors. So expample tenor 1Y should have one curve having points at date(14,15 and 25 September

Comment: @ConfusedLearner what I would like to have is a time series , having curves for each tenor(so total 5)

Comment: I got it now, but the first tenor 5Y is missing. Could you copy and paste in your dataframe `Final_DF`, so that I can test it?

Comment: I have added the data, Could you try now? @ConfusedLearner. I am not adding the full dataset, but the idea is same

Answer (score 0):

I had to restructure your dataframe to one for each tenor:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


tennors = [t for t in Final_DF['TENOR'].drop_duplicates()]
dfs = [Final_DF[Final_DF['TENOR'] == t] for t in tennors]
```

Now plot all dataframes in one figure (you may need to run it in an interactive window cell):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for df in dfs:
    df.plot(x='SNAPSHOT_DATE', y='SPREAD', ax=ax, label=list(df['TENOR'])[0])
```

[image: img]

Works great for me.

Does this answer solve your problem?